# Convert list to string of all dataframe rows

Tags: json, r

I hace the following dataframe:

```
json = '[
  {"id":"1","list":["A","B"]},
  {"id":"2","list":["C","D"]}
]'
df <- fromJSON(json) 
df
```

Output:

```
  id        list
1  1 c("A", "B")
2  2 c("C", "D")
```

Now, I want the list to be a string like this:

```
  id   list
1  1 "A, B"
2  2 "C, D"
```

So, I've tried the following but nothing changes:

```
df$list <- paste(df$list, sep = ", ")
```

I've also tried the following but it concats the two lists in every row:

```
df$list <- toString(df$list)

# Output
  id                     list
1  1 c("A", "B"), c("C", "D")
2  2 c("A", "B"), c("C", "D")
```

Is there a way to change every row separately?

Another solution would be to import the JSON arrays directly to a given format, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to loop through the column and do the `toString`

```
df$list <- sapply(df$list, toString)
```

Comment: If you use paste you have a bit more control over how you combine the individual list elements, e.g. sapply(df$list, paste0,collapse = "-")